# Adding two XML files causes a rendering bug/something. Wat?

Tags: android, drawable, android-xml, android-2.3-gingerbread

Is there some XML/layout/resource limit to Android projects / some point in the compiling toolchain?  Adding a single (unused, any contents) XML layout file to my Android project is causing a rendering bug elsewhere in the app.  Removing it fixes it.  Is this a bug in some part of the compiling toolchain, and how can I diagnose / fix it?

---

**Some additional context:**

I have a relatively large Android project.  Today I ran across a problem while adding a feature: a background-drawable of a button wasn't rendering until I rotated the application.  Other backgrounds / styles / styled buttons are still working, but this one background is very much broken, everywhere in the application.  Rotating fixes the screen it's on, and every later instance of the button, until restarting the application's process.

After a *lot* of trial and error, and bisecting and experimentation, I have some level of a minimal reproduction that is perfectly reliable: adding two more XML layout files to my current project triggers the bug.  Specifically, adding the 40th XML file in the only /res/layout folder.  Removing it lets the button render properly, adding it breaks it.

The files can be completely unused, completely from scratch, with any contents, and any name.  No other project changes.  I'm running an up-to-date version of Eclipse and the Android SDK - I can get specific version numbers if desired.  It has been replicated with this project on a coworker's machine with a similar setup.  I've cleaned, rebuilt, manually deleted build products, restarted my computer, the bug persists.

There must be something more specific causing it, and I would love suggestions to help narrow it down.  Unfortunately it has gone beyond my knowledge of the Android build system, and it doesn't seem to be something directly caused by me.  Can anyone help?  Or point me to some further resources?

---

**More details**:

- (can't believe I forgot this) this only seems to happen on the 2.3.6 devices I have.  It might be happening on other 2.x versions, but a 4.2.2 renders the button correctly all the time (though I haven't / can't rule out a bug in another location).  I'll be trying emulators today.
- Happens on multiple Android devices, though they're all essentially stock (no custom themes, etc).
- Current app setup is a core-app project, with three other projects that use that core project to produce different builds (dev, production, etc) via manifest merging.
- That particular drawable resource has a unique R id as it should, so it doesn't appear to be a collision there.  I have not compared it to system R values - is there a good way to do so?
- Target SDK = 17, minimum = 8

---

**Also interesting**: renaming the drawable file from "rounded_teal_button_normal" to "rounded_teal_button_nrml" doesn't change anything, but changing it to "rounded_teal_button_aargh" *does*.  Only important difference I can see there is that "nrml" doesn't change the alphabetical ordering of the files, while "aargh" does (there's a "_disabled" file, and "_pressed").  This does, however, cause the drawable that is now in the 'normal' position to stop drawing.

Changing the button state-selector's ordering of items or which state gets which drawable (or even removing all other styles) doesn't have any effect.

Adding a *third* XML file causes the problem to disappear, and it doesn't seem to be causing alphabetically-nearby drawables to break, but it's very hard to be sure it's solving *everything*, and the 'why' question remains.

Comment: there's no limit for adding xml layouts to your project. But it will slow down your app. More and more android xml's means more UI to be inflated and rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Some more info is needed to be able to make more educated guesses. Once I had an issue similar to this which was happening on GB versions but not above, only if compiled on a Mac; the same was working fine if compiled on windows; the issue was a background image was not showing up for a button. My background image was a 9-patch and finally I noticed that it was caused by not putting respective images in all drawable-[m|h|x]dpi; I had it only in drawable-xhdpi directory so fixing that fixed the issue. You may check for these types of issues. For example, is this problem showing up only on certain screen densities or certain android versions, etc. As the other response says, 40 xml is far from any limit.

HTH,
Ali.

Comment: This has the drawable in the root 'drawable' folder - it's not an image, it's a 3-item <layer-list> with just colors and shapes.  I don't think(?) it makes a difference if I were to add it to the other locations, and it hasn't been a problem before so I'm inclined to look elsewhere.

I updated the main question with more info - mind taking a look?  And is there any info you'd like?  I'm not really sure what would be useful, and I can't just dump the whole project.

Comment: Try to monitor the log as you navigate to the page that shows the issue and see if there is any error regarding missing id or something that can give some more clues.

Comment: Nothing that looks at all related.  A lot of: 'VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4109' followed by 'VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b' and 'VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f', but that's all in the ActionBarSherlock library (seems like versioned code getting pruned).  That aside, there's nothing that looks at all like an error.

Comment: I did discover that adding a *third* XML layout file causes the problem to disappear... but I'm interested in fixing this, not hiding it (and it seems likely it's just being pushed to some other resource).